# How to get JSON post data in Noir

Tags: clojure, noir

A while back, Chris Granger posted [this middleware](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clj-noir/INqvBo6oXIA/G2hfpUYIpjcJ) to get JSON hashes to appear in the defpage params under an umbrella "backbone" element.

```
(defn backbone [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (let [neue (if (= "application/json" (get-in req [:headers "content-type"]))
       (update-in req [:params] assoc :backbone (json/parse-string (slurp (:body req)) true))
       req)]
    (handler neue))))
```

How could I modify this code to have the JSON elements appear as top-level params in defpage; i.e. get rid of the :backbone umbrella?

Comment: Why do you want this? It seems this could be disastrous if any of the data in the JSON object overrides existing request attributes. Unless that is what you are going for?

Comment: There are no other request attributes.  Everything is posted in JSON format.  That's why the umbrella "backbone" element seems redundant for me.

Comment: Ah, I see it's updating the `:params` key, not the request map... see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you can do. One option is to replace the value of `:params` with the map returned after parsing the JSON. In order to do that, just associate the new map to the `:params` key.

```
(assoc req [:params] (json/parse-string (slurp (:body req)) true))
```

The other option (as suggested by @dAni) is to merge the values of the parsed JSON into so that existing values in the `:params` map are not overridden. The reason why you need to use `partial` instead of just using `merge` here is because the final map is the merged result of the maps from left-to-right. Your solution works if you want the values from the JSON map to take precedence.

```
(update-in req [:params]
  (partial merge (json/parse-string (slurp (:body req)) true)))
```

Comment: I know this is old but can't you just use `body-params` for it with lib-noir?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  `assoc` just works for one element so you have to put everything under the `:backbone` umbrella.  To push *all* the JSON elements into the params, you have to use `merge`.  So change the 4th line to:

```
(update-in req [:params] merge (json/parse-string (slurp (:body req)) true))
```

Comment: or (update-in req [:params] (partial merge (json/parse-string (slurp (:body req)) true))) if you want the exiting params not to be overriden.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind pulling in another dependency, you can use the [ring-middleware-format library.](https://github.com/ngrunwald/ring-middleware-format)

Instructions:

- Add `[ring-middleware-format "0.1.1"]` to your `project.clj`
- and then in your `server.clj`, add the following code:

Code:

```
(:require [ring.middleware.format-params :as format-params])

(server/add-middleware format-params/wrap-json-params)

(defn -main [& m]
; Start the server...
)
```

Now any incoming JSON will be available to use just like form POSTdata.